# Determine how many children a div has

Tags: xml, r

How can I determine how many elments the `div class="pagination"` has, using xml?

```
<div class="pagination">
   <span class="current">
     1
   </span>
   <a class="" href="#">
     2
   </a>
   <a class="" href="#">
     3
   </a>
   <a class="" href="#">
     4
   </a>
</div>
```

The output should just be: 4.

**Update 1:**

I've tried this:

```
library(XML)
urrrl <- "http://www.tagesanzeiger.ch/service/suche/suche.html?order=relevanz&q=Ecopop&submitSearch=Suchen&date=alle#"
download.file(url = urrrl, destfile = "overview.xml")
parsed <- htmlParse("overview.xml") 

nodes <-  getNodeSet(parsed, "//div[@class='pagination']")  
nodes
   list()
   attr(,"class")
   [1] "XMLNodeSet"

aid <- lapply(nodes, function(x) xmlSApply(x, xmlValue))
aid
   list()
```

**Update 2:**

It seems that the problem is somehow related to the fact that there is some underlying script or sth, which enables only to click through all search results by "hand". How to overcome this?
Thanks again

Comment: this XPath : `//div[@class='pagination']/*` return all children element of the `<div>` ...

Comment: @har07 This doesn't work for me. I might make a mistake. Would you write the whole code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `count()` function of XML 1.0.
Here is an example:

```
doc <- htmlTreeParse("http://www.cgalaw.com/contact", useInternal = TRUE)

(string <- xpathSApply(doc, "count(//h3)", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)) 

[1] 5
```

There are five nodes in doc that are h3.  So I think you can run something like

```
xpathSApply(doc, "count(div[@class='pagination'])", xmlValue, trim = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately this returns 0 and not 4. I have solved it in another fashion, but am still keen to learn how else that could be done.

Comment: I left off the closing bracket.  Glad you solved your problem.  Does my revised expression work?

Comment: Unfortunately no... I still get 0.